# Who can provide a mysql 4.0 on Mac OS?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, mac, mac-osx-server

I need a very old version of mysql(4.0.x) on my Mac OS for debugging

and I know the file name format is:

```
mysql-standard-4.0.X-apple-darwinX-powerpc.tar.gz
```

I google some download links,but all valid

Who can provide me a standard version of mysql4.0 on Mac OS? (download link,or email: zenofo#gmail.com)

thanks a lot!

BTW:I know this is a not a real "question",but I very much need it, please forgive me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not compile it on your own? Sources can be had from http://mirror.provenscaling.com/mysql/community/source/4.0/. Open Terminal, change into the directory where you downloaded the tar ball to,

```
$ tar zxvf mysql-4.0.30.tar.gz
$ cd mysql-4.0.30
$ ./configure --prefix=${HOME}/mysql
$ make install
```

, done. The end product can be found in *mysql* in your home directory.

You may need to install Xcode first to get the compiler and all bits and pieces you need to compile software.